# How Do I Save A LZMA file created in JavaScript onto the server?

Tags: javascript, php, binary, xmlhttprequest, lzma

The files i attempt to create with LZMA-JS (https://github.com/LZMA-JS/LZMA-JS) are unusable when trying to save to disk with PHP.

I can successfully decompress a string that i created in JavaScript with the following code. When the compressed file is created in JavaScript at that time.

```
    window.lzma_worker.decompress(bytesArray, window.onTextFinished, window.onTextProgress);
```

onTextFinished just logs decompressed string to console. and it works

How would i convert this data to binary and create a usable archive on the server with php which would work with every LZMA Archive application. All the methods iv tried seem to create a unusable archive.